How to improve the achievement of gradient colormap path?
I follow the link here and here to achieve the gradient colormap of path[pattern like ColorA -- ColorB -- ColorA] in a loop shape of ellipse as below, but it raise the following:
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont! error.
Bucause I'm not so familiar with command
\pgfmathsetmacro\myval{
multiply(divide(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, \pgfdecoratedpathlength),100)};
\pgfsetfillcolor{#1!\myval!#2};

But I guess that the order of the color with some requirements. How to modify it.
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{1,66,126}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{143,30,91}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{72,114,168}
\definecolor{lightred}{RGB}{200,149,174}
\tikzset{
    multicolor/.style n args={3}{
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position \pgfdecoratedpathlength-0.5pt with {\arrow[blue,line width=#3] {>}; },
            mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength-8pt step 0.5pt with {
                \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{multiply(divide(
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, \pgfdecoratedpathlength),100)};
                \pgfsetfillcolor{#1!\myval!#2};
                \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{#3};
                \pgfusepath{fill};}
}}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x[
            evaluate=\x as \y using int(\x*2),
            ] in {0,22.5,...,337.5} {
            \draw[multicolor={darkred}{lightred}{.5pt},overlay,rotate around={\x:(\x:2cm)},thick,blue!40!black] (\x:2cm) ellipse (2.4cm and 1.2cm);
            \draw[multicolor={darkblue}{lightblue}{.5pt},overlay,rotate around={\y:(\y:1cm)},very thick,magenta!50] (\y:1cm) ellipse (2.5cm and 2.2cm);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

What's more, my ideal result is as follows, smoother and more sound, how could I improve my code and assign the start of the lightblue/lightred and end of the darkblue/darkred to better replicate my ideal result.


The cause for the ; missing warning is easy: You're using a ; where it is not needed. Only TikZ paths (\path, \draw, …) need it. Everything else (like \pgfsetfillcolor,  \pgfmath…, …) doesn't.

In the links show at the beginning of question, the original answer also use ; after \pgfsetfillcolor and \pgfmath... And I copy the wheel from them, it goes well. However when I change the color in form as #1 and #2, the nullfont appeared(dizzy)

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{140,30,90}
\definecolor{lightred}{RGB}{220,190,200}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\redN}{8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\redCradius}{1.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\redXradius}{2.4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\redYradius}{1.5}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\redN}{
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=-(\i-0.5)*360/\redN}]
\clip (-\redXradius,0) rectangle (2*\redXradius,-\redYradius);
\shade[top color=darkred, bottom color=lightred, even odd rule] (0:\redXradius-\redCradius) ellipse[x radius=\redXradius, y radius=\redYradius] ellipse[x radius=\redXradius-0.06, y radius=\redYradius-0.12];
\end{scope}
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\redN}{
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=-(\i-0.5)*360/\redN}]
\clip (-\redXradius,0) rectangle (2*\redXradius,\redYradius);
\shade[top color=darkred, bottom color=lightred, even odd rule] (0:\redXradius-\redCradius) ellipse[x radius=\redXradius, y radius=\redYradius] ellipse[x radius=\redXradius-0.06, y radius=\redYradius-0.12];
\end{scope}
}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,65,125}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{170,190,225}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\blueN}{16}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\blueCradius}{0.4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\blueXradius}{2.4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\blueYradius}{1.2}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\blueN}{
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=-(\i-0.5)*360/\blueN}]
\clip (-\blueXradius,0) rectangle (2*\blueXradius,-\blueYradius);
\shade[top color=darkblue, bottom color=lightblue, even odd rule] (0:\blueXradius-\blueCradius) ellipse[x radius=\blueXradius, y radius=\blueYradius] ellipse[x radius=\blueXradius-0.06, y radius=\blueYradius-0.12];
\end{scope}
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\blueN}{
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=-(\i-0.5)*360/\blueN}]
\clip (-\blueXradius,0) rectangle (2*\blueXradius,\blueYradius);
\shade[top color=darkblue, bottom color=lightblue, even odd rule] (0:\blueXradius-\blueCradius) ellipse[x radius=\blueXradius, y radius=\blueYradius] ellipse[x radius=\blueXradius-0.06, y radius=\blueYradius-0.12];
\end{scope}
}

\useasboundingbox (-4.4,-4.4) rectangle (4.4,4.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



So elegant to shade TWO ellipses with different colors to generate the grandient color!

The trick is to create an area (solid ellipse with smaller ellipse cut out). - and this  area can then be shaded. Unfortunately it is needed to use a transform canvas to rotate this shading - this has the side effect that the bounding box needs correcting - here I have just manyally set it (with useasboundingbox).
